# website to collate and minify multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, minify

This might seem a little lazy, but is there any service online that will collect javascript from diverse URLs I could provide and collate them together into one minified file? It would just be easier and more reliable than copy pasting a bunch of different files into one document manually. Again, I admit it's lazy, but I was just wondering..

Thanks!

Comment: `wget` them and them pass them into `uglifyjs` or Google's Closure Compiler.

Comment: ^^`wget http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js | uglifyjs -m -c -o minified.js`

Comment: have a look over it http://jscompress.com/

Comment: not for the lazy ones, but i prefere to setup a grunt project where you can combining different files, doing a `jslint`on all and then doing minification. the problem with online services is that they could go away ;) and then you need to start searching again for a new service.

Comment: @Hariharan Ah, how could I have missed that upload files button. Very careless. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great ti help you. As well as refer CodeKit too. Did my answer helps you @thomas? please make upvote to help other to find as correct anwser too @thomas

Comment: This library could possible help in managing groups of resources like that https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/